# Change action on click if div has a different class

Tags: jquery

I have a number of divs withing a container. When one of the divs is clicked I compare  the ID of that div and the one that has a class "CURRENT" and if they are not the same I do something.

I would like to add another condition, to check if the class "red" is there instead of "green" and if yes, show an alert. I tried the code below but I think I might be checking it wrong, as I get an alert when I click on any div withing "main"...

```
<div id="main">
   <div id="1"><span class="red"></span>Label 1</div>
   <div id="2"><span class="red"></span>Label 2</div>
   <div id="3"><span class="green current"></span>Label 3</div>
   <div id="4"><span class="green"></span>Label 4</div>
</div>

$('#main div').live('click', function() {

   var ct = $('.current').attr('id');
   var cc = $(this).attr('id');

   // need to add conditional statement
   // if ($(this).find('.red')) {
   //    alert("Has red class");

   if (ct != cc) {
      // do something
   }

});
```

Comment: `.current` is `<span>` element, not `<div>` which has an ID attribute. You should use `$('.current').parent().attr('id');` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
if ($(this).hasClass('red')) {
   // do something
}
```

EDIT: Sorry, this assumes, the click event comes from the span itself.

```
if ($('span', this).hasClass('red')) {
   // do something
}
```

should work...

2nd EDIT: You should close your divs... Then:
http://jsfiddle.net/E9948/

Answer (score 1):

The way to check if an element has a class is by using `.hasClass()`

```
if ($('span', this).hasClass('red')){
    alert('has red class');
}
```

What you were doing when you had `.find('.red')` is getting the descendants of `$(this)` which have a class `red`. It doesn't return a boolean, like .hasClass() does.

Also, your `div` `id`s start with a number. That is not the right way. They should start with a letter. And it is a good idea to close the `div` tags. :-)

Here's a [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/utomar/1/edit)

Comment: The class is within a span that's withing div... Won't hasClass be looking at the div?

Comment: You are right, I wasn't thinking straight. :-/ Updated the answer

Comment: Yep, forgot to close but only here in example. Corrected. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative (working sample http://jsbin.com/oqopaw/1/edit):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
  <style>
    #main span{
      cursor:pointer;
    }
    .red{
      background-color:red;
    }
    .green{
      background-color:green;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="main">
   <div id="1"><span class="red">Label 1</span></div>
   <div id="2"><span class="red">Label 2</span></div>
   <div id="3"><span class="green current">Label 3</span></div>
   <div id="4"><span class="green">Label 4</span></div>
</div>
<script>
$('#main span').click(function() {
  if($(this).attr('class').indexOf('current') >= 0) 
  {
    if($(this).attr('class').indexOf('green') >= 0) alert('current green!');
  }
});  
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes, this will work based on my example. In real code, though "current" is not always right after "red" span... Thanks.

Comment: You can organize the logic of your choice. This is just an example, one of the many options